Teaching AI to respect human physical integrity through haptics?
I’m not a specialist, but I’m curious about AI and security.
I was thinking: can we teach AI to understand the human physical body and respect it, to prevent issues like in the paperclip dilemma? Maybe using haptic interfaces to teach AI about physical contact, pain, and consequences, so it excludes humans from harmful actions?
Has this idea been explored? I found research on AI understanding its environment but nothing on making it safer this way.

Not really, because that isn't how the math works, but the paperclip apocalypse is also not how the math works, so it balances out.

The pithy answer is we already have intelligent beings which understand pain and are willing to subject humans to it for “paperclips.”
AI safety is a noble pursuit and empathy for fellow creatures may be a path towards it but we’re a bit far off to tell.
